# How do you multiply numbers in C# through the cmd?

Tags: c#, cmd, multiplication

I am trying to run a program that asks for a number and the user will type a number in, it will then and for a second number and the user will enter another number, the product will then give the result of the 2 number multiplication. How do i go about it?

I already have the console application with:
1. Hello World
2. Print numbers 1 to 10
3. Multiply Numbers
9.Quit

they all work but I'm having a tough time trying to figure out how to multiply numbers, I can do it with set number as x = 5 and y = 3 etc but I want it to be able to multiply 2 numbers that are written into the Command prompt, does anyone have any tips or can point me in the right direction? I'm not asking for it to be written for me, I'm asking for help on a particular part of a working program I have made

Comment: What did you try? What didn't work? Please post your current code and explain where you are having difficulties.

Comment: How far have you got by now? We won't simply write the whole program for you.

Comment: use While ( true ) and read user input then multiple the previous input with the next input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter first number: ");
int m = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Enter second number: ");
int n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("The multiplication of numbers entered = "+ m * n);
Console.ReadLine();
```